# ¿Cómo arreglo la key de los hijos?

Tags: reactjs, warnings

En la consola de mi navegador me aparece esta advertencia que quizás me esté generando ciertos bugs:
Warning each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Lo que me lleva a esta parte de mi código:

```
    <motion.div className="app__skills-list" >
      {skills.map((skill) => (
        <motion.div
          whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
          className="app__skills-item app__flex"
          key={skill.name}
        >
          <div
            className="app__flex"
            style={{ backgroundColor: skill.bgColor }}
          >
            <img src={urlFor(skill.icon)} alt={skill.name} />
          </div>
          <p className="p-text" >{skill.name}</p>
        </motion.div>
      ))}
    </motion.div>
```

¿Qué es lo que debo cambiar sobre la key?

Comment: Se puede hacer una composición con los datos, ahora ahí, en esa pieza de código hay que verificar que no haya un `skill.name` repetido, puede que por esto React se este quejando.

Comment: He usado el buscador del VSC  y las unicas skill.name que hay son las 3 que estan en el codigo mostrado. También intenté por si acaso ponerle skills.name al declarar la key y el error sigue siendo exactamente el mismo.

Comment: oK, tienes un array skills, revisa en este array por el valor name, en cada uno de sus elementos, puede que haya repetidos, ahora bien, esto lo puedes solucionar por ejemplo, usando `index` en el callback de map, tal vez algún colega quiera mostrarnos un ejemplo.

Comment: Tengo otro div en esa misma pagina que usa el .name por ejemplo: work.name y el div es casi identico al codigo mostrado. La solucion sería cambiar ese .name por otra cosa?

Comment: El [tercer ejemplo es tu caso de uso](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), sugiero revisar los otros ejemplos también, por si el array skills contiene la propiedad id, la uses.